# Getting placeholder list from a Velocity template

Tags: java, velocity

suppose I have a Velocity template like this:

```
Hi!, my name is ${name} and I'm ${age} years old.
```

Note the template has no loops or conditional statements.

I would like to get a list with these values

```
["name", "age"]
```

I checked the API but looks like the Template class does not have a method for this: https://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.7/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/Template.html

How can I get this list with using velocity without parsing the template myself?

Comment: I did this, but don't have the source available at the moment. I think I ended up using the visitors, but can't recall the specifics.

Comment: You *might* be able to implement your own `Context`, which adds the keys of calls to `containsKey` or `get` to a `Set<String>`, and use it together with a `NullWriter` (commons-io) in a preprocessing step. Apart from that it somehow feels bad, this also suffers from the theoretical deficiency that nobody *guarantees* (although it should work, I think) that Velocity will invoke either of the two methods because it does not find any keys appearing in `getKeys()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been looking for a way to retrieve a list of all keys used in a Velocity template as well. As mentioned in one of the comments you can implement your own Visitor to run through all the nodes in the Velocity template.

Here's a snippet that stores the keys that are encountered in the template and prints them afterwards:

```
VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("class.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader");
props.put("resource.loader", "class");
ve.init(props);
Template t = ve.getTemplate("templates/my-template.vm");

final List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>();
SimpleNode sn = (SimpleNode)t.getData();
BaseVisitor myVisitor = new BaseVisitor(){
    @Override
    public Object visit(ASTReference node, Object data){
        String key = node.literal();
        keys.add(key);
        return super.visit(node, data);
    }
};
sn.jjtAccept(myVisitor, new Object());
for (String key : keys) {
    System.out.println(key);
}
```

For example if your Velocity template has the following content:

```
<p>Dear ${user.name}, the ordered package has been sent to ${user.address}.</p>
```

The following will be printed:

```
${user.name}
${user.address}
```